# References on generalization bounds

Tags: reference-request, machine-learning, lg.learning, upper-bounds

I'm looking for references (books, papers, lecture notes etc) on generalization bounds and their proofs. Specifically, I'm looking to fully understand the technique of defining a hypothesis class (or distribution) and using a concentration inequality to obtain a generalization bound.

What are the standard references for such techniques?

Comment: https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~shais/UnderstandingMachineLearning/understanding-machine-learning-theory-algorithms.pdf should be a good starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a concise overview the ideas you can read [Mendelson's notes](https://maths-people.anu.edu.au/~mendelso/papers/summer02.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwieoPuvqJzjAhUjMuwKHVTCBVcQFjABegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw2sGYy-mQbnSWWzHIGY2k9U) on the topic.

For a  bit more check out the [outline](https://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~asml162/Class_Material) (and the links in it) by Kontorovich on how the basic and most fundamental bonds where proved.

For a more extended discussinon you can go over lecture notes of statistical learning courses. Here is one for [example](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~bartlett/courses/281b-sp06/).

If books are your favorite kind of learning source, any good theoretic statistical learning book will have chapters discussing the basics. Here's links for two [relevant](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540761209) [books](https://cs.nyu.edu/~mohri/mlbook/).